# How to know what commands are run or what script is sourced when a new terminal is opened?

Tags: terminal, csh

When I open a new terminal, directory is changed to some path (not in my `.cshrc`). I want to know from where does this come from.

Is there a way to know what commands are run or what script is sourced when a new terminal is opened?

Comment: Also look at `~/.login` (if the terminal is configured to start login shells), `/etc/csh.cshrc`, `/etc/csh.login`, `~/.tcshrc` (if csh is actually tcsh), and maybe others. It's all described in the `csh` manpage.

Comment: @Aaron WTH `set -x` does NOT work in csh. `csh -x` does NOT show what startup files it's sourcing and what commands it's running from them -- the `echo` option is only enabled *after* the startup files have been sourced.

Comment: @Aaron and even if `csh -x` worked (it doesn't), all shells (including but not limited to csh, bash or zsh) are sourcing different startup files when called as login shells (with their `argv[0]` starting with a dash), and (depending on how they're configured) many terminal emulators do sometimes run such login shells. Notably `tmux`, but even `xterm` if the `loginShell` resource is set to true, or the `-ls` option was used.

Comment: @user414777 thank you for your feedback, I've deleted my misleading comment